# Redirect based on param value in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Categories` controller where URLs of the form `/categories/:name` route to the `categories#show` action.

I want to redirect `categories/:name/?page=1` to `categories/:name`.

I know I could do the following in `routes.rb`:

```
get '/categories/:name', to: redirect('/categories/%{name}', status: 301),
  constraints: ->(request) { request.query_string =~ /page=1/ }
```

but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Better way is don't redirect. What purpose to do it? Your route is correct and kaminari/will_paginate will handle your page param.

Comment: It's definitely a niche situation but let's say someone goes to page 2, then clicks back to page 1 via a pagination link, I'd prefer they end up back at `mysite.com/categories/category_name` instead of `mysite.com/categories/category_name?page=1`.  The URL looks cleaner and it consolidates the given page into a single canonical URL.